# My mom has been strict in this matter or have been strict?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which is more preferable in this sentence, "has been" or "have been"?

> My mom {has/have} been strict in this matter.

Comment: You just have to conjugate *to have* properly.  Which one is correct conjugation: "My mom *has* a car" or "My mom *have* a car"?  The same principle applies here.

Comment: Please read through [this post on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-can-i-write-a-better-title-for-my-ell-question/4773#4773) and retitle your question accordingly.

Comment: There is also some good advice for writing a question with enough detail in the [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/976/9161) post on [meta]. If we understand why you are asking the question and what you already know about the subject, we can write answers that are more helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You use the word "has" when you are referring to one person/thing (**singular**).

**She has been strict in this matter.**

**My mom has been strict in this matter.**

You use the word "have" when you are referring to many people/things (**plural**).

**They have been strict in this matter.**

**My mom and dad have been strict in this matter.**

Comment: I've added a couple more examples using nouns instead of pronouns.